# Runtime error '91' on visual basic for executing matlab .m file

Tags: matlab, visual-studio, shell, vb6, runtime-error

I want to call matlab & at the same time run .m file from visual basic 6. but I'm getting this run-time error '91', variable not set bla bla. I've searched the internet to find any solution but I couldn't. There is something wrong with my code, I don't know what it is. can anyone please check & see what's wrong?

```
 Private Sub Form_Load()

Dim MatLab As Object
Dim Result As String
Dim MReal(1, 3) As Double
Dim MImag(1, 3) As Double
Dim mat_exe As String
Dim mat_io_folder As String
Dim mat_m As String
mat_exe = "G:\matlab\bin\matlab.exe"
mat_io_folder = "G:\Farin\New folder"

 mat_m = "Untitled.m"
FileName = mat_exe & " " & "addpath('mat_io_folder') & mat_m" & " -s1"
runmatlab = Shell(FileName, 1)
Result = MatLab.Execute("cd G:\Farin\New folder")
Result = MatLab.Execute("Untitled")
'Calling m-file from VB
'Assuming solve_bvp exists at specified location
'Result = MatLab.Execute("cd G:\Farin\New folder\Untitled")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Error 91 in VB6 means object variable not set, which, at a guess, would be the statement

```
result = MatLab.Execute("...")
```

Matlab is declared as an object but it has not been assigned a value.  List of VB6 runtime errors can be found in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264975(v=VS.60).aspx

Another problem is the Filename assignment.  It should read

```
FileName = mat_exe & " " & "addpath('" & mat_io_folder & "') " & mat_m & " -s1"
```

Might be an idea to MsgBox Filename before running the shell command.